# Same Excel macro giving error under different situations

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 Sub() Functions in Excel. Both have different names but same code. but when trying to run together gives an 'Application defined' error. Am not able to understand where the problem is

Following is the code for the same

```
Sub GT456T()

Sheets("Sheet2").Rows("1:1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Rows("11:11").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub



Sub CopyRecord()


Sheets("Sheet2").Rows("1:1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Rows("11:11").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

I dont understand why does it give error when run one after one another. if i run the 1st macro it doesnt throw an error but when executing the second immediately after the first it throw an 'Application defined' error. please help

Comment: Do you mean "Application UNdefined"?

Comment: You say that the error occurs when you run the 2nd macro after running the first. Do you also get the error if you run the first macro twice? Or the second one twice? Also, how are you running them? Manually, or via another bit of code?

Comment: What "different situations"?!

Comment: @Gary: am running the first and then second in that manner. if I run the same macro twice,thrice..no error occurs. Am running the sub() individually using F5. Also if I run in the order second sub() and then first sub(). Still the error occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without more details about the problem, this is guesswork, but here's my shot at it:

The `.Select` method only works on ranges whose parent sheet is currently active. When you run either macro once, Sheet1 ends up being the active sheet when it's done running. Then you try to run either macro again "immediately" after the first, and the macro wants to select something on Sheet2, but Sheet2 isn't active. Sheet1 is. So you get an error.

There, that was my best, most educated guess.

Comment: yeah right, but doesnt this statement take care of making sheet2 active again ' Sheets("Sheet2").Rows("1:1").Select ' ?

Comment: @Sunny: No. You need to activate the sheet first (Sheet.Activate), then select the range using Range.Select. I think Jean-François is right that this is the problem.

Comment: This is one of the many oddities of Excel VBA. Some brilliant Microsoft engineer decided that you have to say `Sheets("Sheet2").Select` (or `.Activate`) before selecting ranges on that sheet with e.g. `Sheets("Sheet2").Rows("1:1").Select`.